# How to run binary from os.execute from code

Tags: go, child-process

I'm trying to build binary with code and run the command against the bin (the bin is CLI)
Via code,

`mytest.go` file

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "build",  "-o", "./integration/testdata/fzr”,)
cmd.Dir = “./testdata"
err := cmd.Run()
```

now after  the code run, I was able to see the `bin` under `testdata` folder 
And now I’m want to run a command like `fzr —help`

Like following

```
cmdOut := exec.Command(“fzr”, “—help”)
cmdOut.Dir = "./testdata/"
err := cmdOut.Run()
```

**I got error**

```
lookPathErr: {
    Name: “fzr”,
    Err: {
        s: "executable file not found in $PATH",
    },
}
```

Now If I take the fzr bin and put it in go/src/bin I was able to run `fzr —help` from the terminal

The project structure is like following

```
myGithubProject/
  |---- integration
   |---- -testdata
    |---- -fzr
   |---- -mytest.go
```

`mytest` is in the same level with the `testadata` and the `fzr` bin is under test data

What could be the problem ?

I try also to provide the full path to the bin with `os.Getwd()` which doesnt help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications accessing the shell, do often not execute the shell initialization/configuration. For example the cron an clearly also go do not execute the shell initialization.

To make your program work add the absolute path to the executable, or alternative the relative path from the location where your application is started from:

```
exec.Command(“./integration/testdata/fzr”, “—help”)
```

(Assuming that the path displayed is your actual path).